# Use the new operator to allocate an array of integers using the parameter as the size of the array within a function

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I've been stuck on this problem and I'm hoping someone can explain where I'm wrong on this. I'm working on an assignment where I need to:

1) Allocate an array that can contain 100 int values by calling allocIntArray and assign the returned pointer to ptr1.

2) Use the new operator to allocate an array of integers using the parameter as the size of the array.

3) Return the pointer that is returned by the new operator.

4) Print out the new array.

I'm trying to print out the array after passing the size I want through the function.

```
int main() {
int *ptr = NULL;
ptr1 = *allocIntArray(100);
cout << ptr1 << endl;
return 0;
}
```

//The function I want to call

```
int *allocIntArray(int size) {
int *newarr = nullptr;

newarr = new int[size];

return newarr;
}
```

However when I call the function, the output comes out as 00F011E8.
I'm currently trying to understand why this is the output and not the first value in the array. (Just the number 1)

I've been having a lot of trouble grasping pointers any help understanding would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks to everyone who took the time to respond. 
From what I understand from assignment directions, I shouldn't need to use vectors. I'm trying to modify my current code to display the array output and this is what currently comes up when I run it.[enter image description here[My current results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMBt4.jpg)

Comment: What is `ptr1`? It would have to be an `int` or assignable from an `int`.

Comment: `allocIntArray(100)` might return a pointer, but `*allocIntArray(100)` dereferences it and you're left with the first `int` (which was not initialized).

Comment: For the future (when you get past the class teaching `new[]` and `delete[]`), please be aware that your "allocIntArray(number_of_elements)" function already exists as part of the Standard.  It goes by the name `make_unique<int[]>(number_of_elements)` and it returns the newly allocated buffer attached to a smart pointer that knows how to deallocate it (you won't have to remember to call `delete[]` on every single exit path).

Comment: With apologies to my colleague whom I'm paraphrasing: Ask for a refund.  What you're taking is not a C++ class, it's a history class.

Answer (score 1):

At first, if you're using C++, you should use std::vector/std::array. This avoids a huge amount of possible problems.

It would look like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    // create array of size 10 and initialize it with 0's
    std::vector<int> vec(10, 0);

    // print array
    for(auto a : vec)
        std::cout << a << '\t';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

If it's some kind of exercise, you have done four big mistakes:

1. you dereference the returned pointer to the array. So you get the value of the first element in the array and not the array itself. Simply remove the *.
2. you print out the address of the first element of the array. To print the array, you have to iterate over each element of the array. This can be done in a for loop:

`for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    std::cout << ptr1[i] << '\t';`

3. you want to print out the array uninitialized. In fact, you try to print out some random values which are there in the memory. At first, you have to assign the elements values.
4. you forget to delete the array by using 
   delete[] ptr1;

Comment: As @eerorika put so well in the deleted answer's comments : *"Note that if an indeterminate value is produced by an evaluation, it is not merely garbage, but behaviour of the program is entirely undefined (exceptions apply)."*

Comment: Thank you for your response. Could you please explain your first point? I tried removing the * from the function and from the pointer and nothing changed when I ran my program. I also added a loop but now it just displays the same line 10 times and they're not integers (image added to the question).
Would you also mind explaining your 3rd point when I have to assign elements values?

Thank you again for your time and help.

Comment: @jtb0216 a pointer is the memory address of a variable. To get the value of a pointer (the value stored at this specific point in memory) you can use the `*`-operator which you can use like `*ptr`. But if you dereference the pointer, you have there a variable which you try to assign to your ptr1 which has the type int* (pointer to int). You still have these undefined values in the memory. So you have to assign each element an own value. This can be done by `ptr1[index] = value;`.

Answer (score 0):

I just have to answer as you seem to be missing some important fundamentals. Either the instructor should be dismissed or you have not paid enough attention in the class. So...

```
ptr1 = *allocIntArray(100);
```

You could not have pasted code that compiles, ptr1 is not declared.
You need to understand what the `*` operator does. What ever value to the right of `*` must be a `pointer`. What a pointer is should be fundamental in your understanding. If you had:

```
int* ptr1 = *allocIntArray(100);
```

You should have gotten a compiler error, so you must have:

```
int ptr1;
```

Somewhere along the line. As `allocIntArray(...)` returns a pointer, then `*allocIntArray(...)` gives you an integer.

You would have wanted to:

```
int* ptr1 = allocIntArray(100);
```

To get a pointer to the new array. Then you:

```
std::cout << ptr1 << std::endl;
```

So, what is ptr1? If it is a pointer then all you are doing is printing the pointer value. Per your stated problem, I'd say ptr1 is in fact a pointer. `std::cout` has not facility to work with a pointer as you expect. At that, it would have no way of determining the size of your array.
You would want to (And it hurts my fingers to write like this):

```
for(size_t i= 0; i < 100; ++i)
    std::cout << ptr1[i] <<" ";
```

But!!!

> 4) Print out the new array.

So what will it print? There was never an instruction to initialize the array. It will print out what ever garbage is sitting in the array when it was created.

Side note, that the instructor has you doing a:

```
using namespace std;
```

Says much, as he/she should never have allowed it.